# getting sensor event listener on a separate thread

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I'm writing an app that gets the phone rotation from the rotation vector sensor and sends the values over a socket to my PC.

I want to implement a `SensorEventListener` in a way that the callback to `onSensorChanged()` will be made in a separate thread in order to make the UI thread more responsive. For my understanding onSensorChanged will be called very often so i want to separate all the callbacks from the UI thread.

Is it possible to do that?

I'm new in android programming and really need help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Acclerometer Sensor in Separate Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513352/acclerometer-sensor-in-separate-thread)

Answer (score 0):

You should handle your SensorListeners in a separate [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Just create a new thread from the Service, invoking a specific function (which will register the Listener and process received data).

```
task = new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        receive_and_treat_info();
    }
};
task.start();

void receive_and_treat_info(){
    register_your_listeners();
    treat_them();
}
```

Comment: so if i understand you. i need to: create a class that extends Service. create and start the service from my main thread. inside the service run a new thread and inside the thread register my listener? but who implements the listener? The service?

Comment: That's right. I don't really recall if you have to implements the Listener interface for the sensors (i don't think so). Service and Activites share the same application context and will receive the sensor events, so you shouldn't worry about who implements what anyway.